# How to give the permission to talk on a gallery chat

Tags: support

I have created a chat to help a single user, so I made it a gallery where only approved users can talk.

But I don't find any way to give the permission to that user to talk here, how should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That option is on the access tab of the chat room information page. At the top you can toggle the option for gallery chat room

[image]

and below that you can grant users write access

[image]